# OS X stealth mode: where is it enacted?

Tags: macos, mac, security, firewall, osx-mountain-lion

I am working through the [security guide from apple](http://www.apple.com/support/security/guides/) (which they did not update since Snow Leopard). In the firewall section it states that ipfw has a default allow rule:

```
65535 allow ip from any to any
```

And if you enable the firewalls 'stealth mode' via the settings the following rule should be added:

```
33300 deny icmp from any to me in icmptypes 8
```

The funny thing is: I have stealth enabled and I do not see this rule when doing

```
sudo ipfw print
```

Any idea where stealth mode is enforced if not in the ipfw ruleset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recent versions of OS X use primarily use the application firewall, not ipfw. In the app firewall, you can enable stealth mode with the command:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --setstealthmode on
```

Note that this only takes effect if the app firewall is running. To enable it from the command line, use:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --setglobalstate on
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any resources at hand that describe the socketfilterfw in more detail?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much documentation, although google will point you at various people's experimentation & results. For the socketfilterfw command itself, `/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw -h` is the best resource I know.

Comment: Played around with that. Thx.